# CSS visited links- how to recognize visited links which visited by clicking through my app?

Tags: javascript, css, visited

I want to change the colour of visited links in my app.
The problem that visited referrers to any visit which occurred in my browser. How can I recognize only visits which occurred by clicking on a link which display in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a eventListener or an onclick event to all of you links. Then add unique IDs to all of the links and add them to a cookie.
When you load your app, just read out the created cookie and change the class name to something like "already_visited"

EDIT:

```
<a id="link1" href="page1.html">link 1</a>
<a id="link2" href="page2.html">link 2</a>
<a id="link3" href="page3.html">link 3</a>

<style type="text/css">
    .already_visited{
        color: #f00;
    }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

    window.addEventListener("load", function function_name(argument){
        var links = eval(getCookie("links_visited"));
        for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
            document.getElementById(links[i]).classList.add("already_visited");
        }
    });

    /* Add events to all links */
    function callback(e) {
        var e = window.e || e;

        if (e.target.tagName !== 'A'){
            return;
        }

        /* call cookie function */
        addToVisited(e.target.id);
    }

    if (document.addEventListener){
        document.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
    }
    else{
        document.attachEvent('onclick', callback);
    }

    /* cookie function */
    function addToVisited(link_id){
        var ids = getCookie("links_visited");

        if (ids == "") {
            setCookie('links_visited', '["'+link_id+'"]', 365);
        }
        else if(ids.indexOf(link_id) == -1){
            var id_array = eval(ids);
            id_array.push(link_id);
            setCookie("links_visited", '["'+id_array.join('","')+'"]', 365);
        }

        console.log(getCookie("links_visited"));
    }

    /* cookie function helpers */
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }

</script>
```

The code should be self-explanatory, but ask if anything is unclear to you

Comment: how can I add the id to a cookie?

Comment: The problem that the links are dynamic (each user can enter a link in some fields). So I can't give the  unique id.

Comment: Just add an id to every link, the user creates. It's very difficult to know what you mean, without seeing your code. If there is a button like `create link` that calls a specific function, just add `newlink.id = "someUniqueID"` to it.

Comment: @ Felix Bernhard- there are no buttons. The user just enter text and with a function which called linkify() the application recognize if there is any links in the text.